# Encountering JavaScript Error While Loading Website in Android WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get my Android WebView to play nice, but I'm stuck on this weird error. Here's my Kotlin code snippet:

```kotlin
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
 webView.clearCache(true)
                webView.clearHistory()
                webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
                webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                webView.settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)
                webView.settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true)
                webView.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
                webView.settings.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com")
```

To catch website-related errors, I'm using this `onConsoleMessage` override:

```kotlin
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
        // Logging JavaScript errors here
        Log.e("JAVASCRIPT_ERRORS", consoleMessage.message())
        return true
    }
}
```

But guess what? I keep running into this bizarre error:

```
n[(h + P3)] is not a function
```

Strangely, the same site works like a charm on Chrome mobile/PC, but the WebView on my app is giving me a headache. Any thoughts on what might be going on? I'm all ears!

Comment: This is _almost certainly_ something wrong with the JavaScript code itself.  You'll probably need to include it here to get an answer.

Comment: The website's JavaScript code is heavily obscured also quite lengthy to share it here. If it were a JavaScript-specific issue, it wouldn't function properly on other browsers. however as I've mentioned it runs on them. The crux seems to lie in how Android WebView interprets the JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all I had to do is updating my [Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) because the older version on my phone wasn't compatible with the website's JavaScript.